# Show that the theory of abelian groups is not Henkin

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

A theory $\Gamma$ is called Henkin if when $\Gamma \vdash \exists x \varphi(x)$ we have that there is a constant c such that $\Gamma \vdash \varphi(c)$. Now, I am asked to show that the theory of abelian groups in the language $\{ \circ,e,()^{-1}\}$ is not Henkin. My idea is trying to find a fact about abelian groups which has a non constructive proof but I don't really know any of those.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\varphi(x)$ be the statement $(\forall y (x = y)) \lor (x \ne e)$. Then $\Gamma \vdash \exists x \varphi(x)$, but the witness to it in a given abelian group won't be your constant symbol $e$ unless the group is trivial.